# Checking in for-each loop xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML with multiple Rows data.

```
<abc>
 <def>some text1</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow</xyz>
</abc>
<abc>
 <def>some text2</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow 2)</xyz>
</abc>
<abc>
 <def>some text</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow 3)</xyz>
</abc>
```

Now I want to write code for this in  **XSL 1.0** where it will start checking for each Row i.e in  whether in element  the value/text "2)" only exists or not.
Whenever it first meets the text "2)" during the loop it should print "XSL_1.0 Programming" as value and should quit the loop.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried to use position and boolean functions but didn't achieved anything because we can check till the value "2)" is coming or not for <xyz>. But I am not able to break the loop whenever it achieves it. I am not getting the idea for breaking the loop.

Comment: And would you be so kind as to _show_ us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this in the wrong way - XSLT is not a procedural language and there's no way to "quit the loop".  Instead you need to think about how to identify the nodes you are interested in in a more declarative way.  For example the XPath expression

```
abc[contains(., '2)')]
```

identifies all `abc` elements that contain the string "2)" anywhere in their descendant text nodes, so

```
(abc[contains(., '2)')])[1]
```

would extract just the first such element, or an empty node set if there are no elements that match.  If you wanted to process the `abc` elements up to and including the first one containing "2)", but not any following ones you could use something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="abc[not(preceding-sibling::abc[contains(., '2)')])]">
```

Comment: I have to add this under xsl:when condition in which this syntax is not acceptable.

Comment: @Kundan please edit the question and show us the XSLT code you have so far.  Like I say, XSLT has no concept of "breaking out of a loop", you have to determine which nodes you want to process before you start the for-each or apply-templates

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="abc">
 <xsl:when test="contains(xyz,'2)')">
  <xsl:text>XSL_1.0 Programming</xsl:text>
 </xsl:when>
</xsl:for-each>

This loop wil work for every <abc> element.
But I want that when it gets 2) first time then it should print the text value and doesnot execute it further.

Comment: @Kundan I've edited my answer with a suggestion that might help.  But fundamentally, it is _impossible_ to break out of a for-each prematurely.  XSLT is a functional language and `for-each` is not necessarily implemented as a loop.  Each node is processed independently of all the others and it's perfectly acceptable for the processor to process all the different nodes in random order or even in parallel in different threads, as long as it produces the final output in the right order.  You have to decide which nodes you want _before_ you start the for-each.

Comment: Thanks Ian. But that does not resolve my problem as again it is printing XSL_1.0 Programming multiple times whenever it gets in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Ian Roberts, there is no concept of breaking out a loop in XSLT. You have to decide in advance what nodes you want to process, and it sounds like you are only interesting in elements up to, and including, the first **abc** element with the '2)' in.

It may actually be better to use **xsl:apply-templates** here.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="abc[not(preceding-sibling::abc[contains(xyz, '2)')])]" />
```

So, this selects all elements that don't have a preceding '2)' element.

Next, you can add templates to match the **abc** elements depending on the contents of the **xyz** element. For example, to output "XSL_1.0 Programming" if it has a '2)' in do the following

```
<xsl:template match="abc[contains(xyz, '2)')]">
    <xsl:text>XSL_1.0 Programming</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="abc[not(preceding-sibling::abc[contains(xyz, '2)')])]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="abc">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(xyz, '&#10;')" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="abc[contains(xyz, '2)')]">
        <xsl:text>XSL_1.0 Programming&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML (Note it has a root element)

```
<root>
<abc>
 <def>some text1</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow</xyz>
</abc>
<abc>
 <def>some text2</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow 2)</xyz>
</abc>
<abc>
 <def>some text3</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow</xyz>
</abc>
<abc>
 <def>some text</def>
 <xyz>stack overflow 3)</xyz>
</abc>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
stack overflow
XSL_1.0 Programming
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<xsl:if test="abc[contains(xyz, '2)')]"> 
   <xsl:text>XSL_1.0 Programming</xsl:text> 
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Again, the same thing follows. This solution works for multiple time, but what I need is when it gets value for the first time then only that should print and loop should be breaked. Whenever it encounters value 2) then the text should be printed one time only and not multiple times.

Comment: That's exactly what it will do: print the value only once.  I'm suggesting you use this _instead of_ the `for-each` loop, not inside it. If this is not adequate for your requirements, please **show us your XSLT** as I asked you to do 35 minutes ago.